# Running Webpack with different entry point each time, but still use a config file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, browserify

I have a project which holds code for numerous different websites. These are not websites that I build or maintain, I just build components for them and deliver these bits of code to be implemented on the site.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
.
+-- tsconfig.json
+-- site_A
|   +-- component1
|   |   +-- component1.html
|   |   +-- component1.css
|   |   +-- component1.js
+-- site_B
|   +-- component2
|   |   +-- component2.ts
+-- my_modules
|   +-- module1.ts
|   +-- module2.ts
|   +-- module3.ts
```

The `my_modules` folder holds functions I use frequently across many components, and therefore I would like to write them as reusable modules. My problem is, that since this is not a single project, I can't really run a single build script on all of it, but actually need to specify the entry point each time I run Webpack.

What I'm currently using as a solution is the following npm build script:

`"build": webpack --module-bind 'js=babel-loader' --module-bind 'ts=ts-loader' --output-path './build' --output-filename '[name].js'`

and I pass it the entry point as an argument. However, this prevents me from using a `webpack.config.js` file, and all its advanced capabilities.

Is there a way I can use a config file and still be able to specify the entry point when running the build? I'm also open for suggestions on other module bundlers if they would offer a better experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to pass in an environment variable that contains the name of the module you want to build like `webpack --env.site=siteA`, then in your config file you can access it like this:

```
    module.exports = env => {
      return {
        entry: env.site + '/src/index.js',
        output: {
          filename: env.site + '.js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
        }
      }
    }
```

Useful links:

https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options

https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/